# libSwiftCore.dylib _hidden, can't figure out what this is?

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I got a crash report with the following [image]

But I can't figure out what caused this, since I can't jump to the source?

Comment: The top of the stack trace is the last function called. The bottom of the stack trace is what triggered that sequence of events leading to the top. Look further down for the cause of the error.

Comment: I added the wrong image of the crash, my bad. Can you lead me to what the problems is above?

Comment: It looks like its crashing before your app even runs properly. It's trying to instantiate a controller and present it (most likely your very first controller).

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the last stack frame for a line of code you wrote.  Based on `swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional`, it looks like you had a `as!` line and the cast did not succeed.

The line you are pointing to is just part of the code that is called once the error is detected.